# Change language in my App on Android 8

Tags: android, kotlin

I can not change my application to another language on Android 8.0

my code:
**Application class**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

companion object {
    fun changeLanguage(context: Context, lang: String) {
        Log.e(context.packageName, lang)
        val locale = Locale(lang)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = context.resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        context.createConfigurationContext(config)
        context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)

        val sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        sharedPreference.edit().putString("lang", lang).apply()
    }
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    val sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    val lang = sharedPreference.getString("lang", "en")

    changeLanguage(this, lang)
  }
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    val lang = sharedPreference.getString("lang", "en")
    if (lang == "en") {
        switchLanguage.setText(R.string.english)
    } else {
        switchLanguage.setText(R.string.viet)
    }
    switchLanguage.isChecked = lang != "en"
    switchLanguage.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, b ->
        if (!b) {
            MyApplication.changeLanguage(baseContext, "en")
        } else {
            MyApplication.changeLanguage(baseContext, "vi")
        }

        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
      }
   }
}
```

When first run app:
[image: first run]

When I change language to Vietnamese, toolbar not change language
[image: toolbar not change language]

When I kill app and reopened all textview convert to english
[image: all textview convert to english]

sorry my English

Comment: What error you are getting? Did you try to debug?

Comment: @VicJordan Application can not retain the Vietnamese language after being killed.
This code works fine with android 7 and lower.

Comment: do you have translation of Hello Word  and  Change Language in vietnam

Comment: @RahulChaudhary yes. You can see it in photo 2

Comment: Try [commit instead of apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/6296561)

Answer (score 0):

##### The problem is on restarting the activity.

Instead of `finish()` and `startActivity(intent)`, use **`recreate()`** method to recreate the current activity, the new language.

Change `setOnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
switchLanguage.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, b ->
    if (!b) {
        MyApplication.changeLanguage(baseContext, "en")
    } else {
        MyApplication.changeLanguage(baseContext, "vi")
    }
    recreate()
}
```

Check your `strings.xml` also for both languages.

> If a string is missing in the translated language, it will get back to the default language.

This approach is working on Android 8.0 and above.

---

Android 8.0 introduced `locale list` that allows to use multiple languages in order of preference.

You need this API provided by Android to create new config with `locale list` and update the app's resources and activity.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

  companion object {
      fun changeLanguage(...) {
          val locale = ...
          // Set Default Locale

          val resources = ...
          val configuration = ...
          // Configuration

          val localeList = ...
          // Configuration

          // Resources with metrics if needed

          // get default share preferences
      }
  }

  override fun funName(...Context) {
      // super.attackBaseContext(updateBaseLocale(...))
  }

  private yourFunName {
      
      // Shared Preferences
      
      // Locale

      // Resources

      // Configuration

      return ...(...)
  }

}
```

`updateBaseLocale` creates new `Context` this method being called `attachBaseContext`.